# yii2 failed to acess file in newly generated folder in frontend/web/assets

Tags: yii2, cpanel, assets

I have this problem in most of my yii2 projects. I got this error:

copy(/var/www/vhosts/gunungkombengtetapselalujaya.com/httpdocs/frontend/web/assets/56687de2/yii.activeForm.js): failed to open stream: Success

I have contacted my hosting provider but they didn't give me any solutions at all so I'm at lost. I have tried to delete all folder in frontend/web/assets but the newly generated one still give this error. I search inside those newly generated folders and some files are not available, like yii.js and others, which might caused error mentioned above. It's as if frontend/web/assets is not writeable, but I checked the file permission and it's already 755.

this is my configuration for assetmanager

```
'linkAssets' => false,
'bundles' => [
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
        'jsOptions' => [ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD ],
    ],
],
'forceCopy' => true,
```

What could be the problem? It's still ok yesterday, but early this morning this happens. Please help.

**UPDATE**

I change linkAssets to true:

```
'linkAssets' => true,
'bundles' => [
    'yii\web\JqueryAsset' => [
        'jsOptions' => [ 'position' => \yii\web\View::POS_HEAD ],
    ],
],
'forceCopy' => true,
```

It can be opened, but the files in newly generated folder are having 403 error when I access them.

Answer (score 0):

I suppose that PHP is running as another user. That's why it has no permission to write files to this folder.
Try to set the permissions to 0777.